# Which state does this area belong to?

Tags: geography

I'm not a native English speaker and I'm learning the US state names and capitals. Which state does green arrow pointed area belong to?

[image]

I highlighted it on Google Map.
[image]

It's the blue dashed line surrounded part.

Comment: This is a geography question, not a Geographic Information Systems Question, and will be closed. The answer is in the ignored dotted line, that separates Maryland from Virginia just north of Chinoteague, VA. The peninsula is referred to as "DelMarVa" and your second picture made it Red-Del and Blue-MarVa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The portion above the dotted line belongs to Maryland, and the portion below belongs to Virgina:

[image]